# Could someone help me understand if all sample within this are control group?

Tags: r, sequence-analysis, gene-expression

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE117872

I'm teaching myself sequence analysis.

**This is the count data:**
[image]

**and then this is, what I believe to be, the coldata:**
[image]

All I want to know is if I can perform Differential Gene Expression analysis on this using just the `drug_status` column since it seems like the second dataset already has results to it.

What would be the reference if listings are either Sensitive, Resistant, or Holiday?

Thank you.